# Changing in Code Specific Row Heights in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView that uses prototype cells to recreate a table.  I have the first row with height 30 and the rest default 44.  I would like to change only first row's height but have failed to do so.  I tried cellForRowAtIndexPath but I learned here that it's heightForRowAtIndexPath: I'm interested in.  However, all the IndexPath's that get sent to it are [0,0].  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 0) { //first row
        return 30;
    }
    else {
        return 44;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this for resizing the cells in your table views delegate.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
        return 30.0;
    return 44.0;
}
```

If this doesn't work: give us your code

Comment: that's what I tried but each index path that gets sent to it appear as [0,0] so it's an all or nothing situation.  I'm using reuseIdentifiers to recreate each individual cell (one for each).  I suppose that's why the index path is all [0,0].  us there a way around this?